# how to insert section into table view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view that contains 120 numbers. I was wondering if it is possible to add a section in my tableview after every 12 numbers. This would be easier than having 10 separate arrays of 12 numbers and adding each array to a different section. 
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading your question and wondering if I'm missing something here, but: Yes, it's possible.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 10;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 12;
}
```

...and then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, use `indexPath.section * 12 + indexPath.row` as the index into your 120-number array.

Comment: I said 6 sections but ur right, it should be 10 sections of 12 numbers haha. thanks, I'm going to try that!

Comment: i understand better now how indexPath.row and indexPath.section increment themselves as you scroll down your table view. it works like a charm. thanks!